# If I exit the game during a battle, can I resume it later?

Tags: card-hunter

What happens when you close your browser before finishing a battle? Does the game save your progress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience:

I was in a battle, then I closed it. When I re-opened the page, the page said this:

[image: Screenshot]

When I clicked "Yes", I returned to exactly where I was.

Comment: It seems like they've added this as a new feature since I tested it. Good to know. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

**Edit: This answer is outdated. It is now possible to resume a battle (See the accepted answer).**

Exiting the game before finishing a battle will count as a failure. This means that you'll need to replay the battle, provided you have some attempts left. If the battle was part of a larger adventure module (eg. White Skull Canyon in the example below), your progress in the module will be preserved. You will just have to replay the battle that you were doing when you closed the browser. Here's the screen that I saw when I closed my browser during a battle and then started the game again:

[image]

Comment: This is odd. I had a completely opposite experience

Comment: @SaintWacko I think we just have a difference in terminology. Closing the browser in the middle of a battle will forfeit that battle (which is what I meant by a failure). You can still resume the adventure module where you left off as you'll have 2 more attempts to complete the battle. I updated my answer to clarify that.

Comment: Hm, mine didn't take one of the three attempts, but I may have closed it between battles.

Comment: @SaintWacko That could be, closing between battles doesn't penalize you.

Answer (score 0):

If you close the browser during a battle, you will have to restart the current battle you are in, but it does not count as a failure, and you do not have to redo the entire dungeon. When you log back in, you will be on the campaign map with your party on the dungeon you were in. If you click on your party, you will be placed back in the dungeon on this screen:

[image]

If you instead click on another location, you will get this popup:

[image]